# CSS (disjointed) problem when additional HTML is added to page

Tags: html, css

I have a basic HTML page with two input fields, one text and one button.  When the textfield has the focus I want the button to be hidden.  I have it working fine providing I do not add any more HTML code (which I wish to do) between the two input tags.

I know I could do this with jQuery but ideally I would prefer a CSS based solution.

```
<style>
   input[type="text"]:focus + input[name="submitButton"]{
   visibility: hidden;
}
</style>

<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" />
```

If I add the additional two 
 statements between the two  tags it fails to work.

```
<input type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" />
```

I know I could use jQuery but i would prefer a CSS solution.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man... i solved your problem

HTML

```
<input type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" class="btn" name="submitButton" />
```

CSS

```
input[type=text]:focus ~ input[type=submit]
{
  visibility:hidden;
}


vote if it helps
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the submit button with a class... dont give input[name,=""]
.

Instead give classname... i think + selector is the problem.. it is searching for immediate adjacent input tags..and it fails to fetch becoz of br tag inbetween....
So target with classname

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I have just tried it but I still cannot get it doing what I would like to.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your CSS and add the line break spacing for the text field in CSS. See an example without having to use`<br>` tags.

```css
input[type="text"]:focus+input[name="submitButton"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" />
```